# Getting specific data with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I used `page.prettify()` to tidy up the HTML, and this is the text that I want to extract now:

```
        <div class="item">
         <b>
          name
         </b>
         <br/>
         stuff here
        </div>
```

My target is to extract the `stuff here` from there, but I am stumped as it is not wrapped in any tags except that `div`, which has other stuff in it already. And also the additional whitespace in front of every line makes it harder.

What would be the way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of find and nextSibling works for the example that you posted.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(""" <div class="item"> <b> name </b>  <br/>  stuff here </div>""")
soup.find("div", "item").find('br').nextSibling
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are really sure, you want to pick up content ending just before the last  and starting after a particular tag, you can use RegExp after this point, not the most elegant, but if your are requirements are specific, it might work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.contents` property of the `div` element to get all elements directly within it, then pick out the one that's a string.

**Edit:**

This was the approach I was alluding to:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import NavigableString

soup = BeautifulSoup("""<div class='item'> <b> name </b>  <br/>  stuff here </div>""")
div = soup.find('div')
print ''.join([el.strip() for el in div.contents if type(el) == NavigableString])
```

Comment: That won't help, it will simply return a list with first item, as the entire content.